# For what values for parameter b will x have real results? $\frac{2x}{x+3}+\frac{bx-2x}{x^2-9}=\frac{x-1}{x-3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, fractions

For what values of parameter b will x have real results?
$$ \frac{2x}{x+3}+\frac{bx-2x}{x^2-9}=\frac{x-1}{x-3}$$
I get to the point where I have: $x^2-(10-b)x+3=0$. If I need real results for x then D needs to be >0 but when I do that I get $b^2-20b+88>0$. What am I supposed to do with that? There is no way I can get b like that.

Comment: Why do you say "There is no way I can get b like that"? To get a $b$ with $b^2-20b+88\ge 0$ is possible, right? For example, $b=0$ is possible. For the general solution, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It should be $$b^2-20b+88\geq0.$$
Also, you need to check $$3^2+(b-10)3+3=0$$ and $$(-3)^2+(b-10)(-3)+3=0.$$
In these cases we obtain:

1. $b=6$, which gives $x^2-4x+3=0$, which gives a root $1$;
2. $b=14$, which gives $x^2+4x+3=0$ and a root $-1$.

Thus, $b=6$ and $b=14$ they are valid.

Comment: Sorry Michael for the dumb question but why we need also $(-3)^2+(b-10)(-3)+3=0$? Maybe I’m loosing something.

Comment: Because the domain gives $x\neq3$ and $x\neq-3$. We need to check this case because we can get for example $(x+3)^2=0.$ If so then $b=14$ is not valid. It's a general reasoning. In our case it's impossible of course.

Comment: I don’t fully understand your reasoning, since $x\neq \pm3$ are conditions independent by b, or am I wrong?

Comment: If for $x=-3$ the equation $x^2+(b-10)x+3=0$ has root $-3$ only then the value of $b$ for which it happens is not valid.

Comment: I would say that b value is valid but x value $\pm3$, don’t, indeed we have also others valid roots $\pm1$? That’s where I’m not following your way.

Comment: Yes, and we can say that $b=14$ and $b=6$ they are valid. See please better my reasoning.

Comment: Ok you have veryfied that for any value of b you have both unacceptable roots for x?

Comment: If so notice that, as an alternative, we can also check the cases with $\Delta=0$ since only these can lead to such situation.

Comment: Also, in the general we can get a linear equation with root $-3$. For our problem it's impossible of course.

Answer (score 1):

For

$$x^2-(10-b)x+3=0$$

to have real solutions we need

$$\Delta=b^2-20b+88\color{red}{\ge} 0$$

from here we can find the range for $b$ by the roots of the quadratic equation.

Note that for the solution of the original equation you also need to set $x\neq \pm 3$.

Comment: I already did that as stated in the question. How do I get b from that?

Comment: This is as far as the OP got by him/herself. How does your answer help further?

Comment: You need to consider the $\ge$ inequality, then use quadratic formula to get the roots $b_1$ and $b_2$.

Comment: Using the quadratic formula I get the square root of 48 in it. That is my main problem like I stated.

Comment: Once you find the roots you can find when $\Delta\ge0$ http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=b%5E2-20b%2B88%3D0

Answer (score 0):

If you already know that $b^2-20b+88\ge 0$, then go on: $(b-10)^2-100+88\ge 0$, then $(b-10)^2\ge 12$. Now you surely can finish it.

Answer (score 0):

$b^2-20b+88\ge0$

Solving the related equation $b^2-20b+88=0$ using the quadratic formula, $b=10\pm2\sqrt{3}$.

So, $(b-(10+2\sqrt{3}))(b-(10-2\sqrt{3}))\ge0$, which means $b\ge10+2\sqrt{3}$ or $b\le10-2\sqrt3$

Also, $x^2-10x+bx+3=0 \rightarrow bx=-x^2+10x-3\rightarrow b=\cfrac{-x^2+10x-3}{x}$ where $x\ne0$.